# Geometric proof about rational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-geometry, rational-numbers

Given,

$$b\in \Bbb Q\implies \exists \;p,q\in \Bbb Z:\:b=\frac pq \wedge q \ne 0 $$

Any line passing through $(0,b)$ and $(1,0)$ such that $\forall \;b \in \Bbb Q$, intersect the unit circle at a rational point $(x,y)$ such that 
the slope of the line through $(0,b)$ and $(1,0)$ is $m=-\frac pq$. Since we want points on the unit circle we know $x^2+y^2=1$. 
So we want the rational points $(x,y)$ where boths graphs intersect, hence I tried to set both equations equal to each other
$$y-mx-b=x^2+y^2-1$$
$$y+\frac pq \left(x-1\right)=x^2+y^2-1$$
I always run into counter example of irrational $x$ and $y$ having rational squares. Therefore, I wonder if my intuition is wrong.

So instead of trying to find the intersecting rational points on the unit circle and the line when the $y$-intercept is $b \in \Bbb Q$, I tried another approach. Basically, what I'm seeing is that since $x^2+y^2=1$ the hypotenuse $h$ of any triangle of sides $x$ and $y$ is equal to 1. The angle $\phi$ between the $x$-axis and the hypotenuse is $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac b1\right)=\tan^{-1}\left( \frac yx\right)$ from similar triangles. Does it follow that
$$\tan\phi = b = \frac yx \in \Bbb Q \implies \exists\;r,s,t,u\in\Bbb Z : x=\frac rs \wedge \frac tu \wedge s,u \ne 0$$
is true? This would mean that $\cos \phi = x \in \Bbb Q:x = \frac rs$ and $\sin \phi = y \in \Bbb Q : y = \frac tu$ and I would claim that 
$$ (i)  \quad \forall \; b \in\Bbb Q \implies \exists \; p,q \in \Bbb Z : q \ne 0 \wedge b = \frac pq = \tan \phi = \left( \frac yx \right)$$
$$(ii) \qquad \exists \; r,s,t,u, \in \Bbb Z : x = \frac rs \wedge y = \frac tu \wedge s,u \ne 0$$
$$\therefore \quad (i) \implies (ii)$$

Is this correct? Does this show that for the infinitely many points on the unit circle, those points $(x, y)$  intersected by a line passing through $(0, b\in\Bbb Q)$ and $(1, 0)$ are rational such that $\forall \;b \in \Bbb Q \implies \left(x = \frac rs, y = \frac tu \right)$? If not, am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest proof I can think of follows your intuition, via trigonometry: Let the line make an angle of $\theta$ with the $x$-axis.  Then it intersects the circle in two points: $(1, 0)$ itself, and $(-\cos 2\theta, \sin 2\theta)$.  We will show that both coordinates are rational.  (Don't read any further if you don't want more than that hint—I couldn't tell if you don't want to be spoiled.)

[image]

First, we see that $\tan \theta = b$.  Then

$$
\cos \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}
$$

and

$$
\sin \theta = \frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}
$$

Since $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta-1$ and $\sin 2\theta = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$, we have

$$
x = -\cos 2\theta = -\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}
$$

and

$$
y = \sin 2\theta = \frac{2b}{1+b^2}
$$

The above image depicts $0 < b < 1$, though that needn't be the case.

Comment: For the second and third quadrant I understand how $x$, and $y$ are rational and dependent on $b$ since I make use of double angles formulas which involves squares, yet in the first and fourth quadrant I use $y= \sin \theta$ and $x= 1- \cos \theta$, how can I get rid of the radical $\sqrt {1+b^2}$ ?

Comment: How did you get $x = 1-\cos\theta$?

Comment: I used the same angle $\theta$ between the $x$-axis and the line passing through $(1, 0)$

Comment: You should still obtain $x = \cos\theta$; it's just on the other side of the $y$-axis.

Comment: I thought that $x= \cos \theta$ would be the case of the angle between the $x$-axis and a line passing through the origin $(0, 0)$, since $x$ is the distance from the origin and I take the angle between the $x$-axis and the point $(1, 0)$ I would have subtracted the $\cos \theta$ from $1$ to get $x$

Comment: How would $x =\cos \theta =\frac 1{\sqrt {1+b^2}}$ and $y = \sin \theta = \frac b{\sqrt {1+b^2}}$ imply that $x$ and $y$ are rational from knowing that $b \in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: It wouldn't, but I'm having trouble visualizing what it is you're describing.  Let me read it more carefully when I have more time and see if I can see what you're seeing.

Comment: I got it! It was a silly mistake, I stopped using the angle $2\theta$ when $b \gt 1$ because from there $2\theta \gt \frac \pi2$, so indeed $x= \pm\cos 2\theta $ is correct. I think that $x=\pm\cos2\theta = 1-cos \theta$ is also correct its just that the double angle formula gets rid of the radical.

Answer (score 1):

For $b\ne 0:$ A point $(x,y)$ on the line satisfies $x+y/b=1,$ that is $$x=1-y/b.$$ A point $(x,y)$ on the circle satisfies $$|x|=\sqrt {1-y^2}.$$ So if both of these hold then $$(1-y/b)^2=x^2=1-y^2$$ which simplifies to $$-2y/b+y^2/b^2=-y^2.$$ Now this holds when $y=0$ iff $x=1-y/b=1-0/b=1$. For the other point, if $y\ne 0$ and $-2y/b+y^2/b^2=-y^2$ then $$-2/b+y/b^2=-y,$$ which is equivalent to  $$y=2b/(b^2+1),$$ implying $$x=1-y/b=(b^2-1)/(b^2+1).$$ If $x,y$ are both rational it is necessary that $b$ is rational because $b\ne 0\implies y=2b/(b^2+1)\ne 0$ which implies (from $x+y/b=1$) that $1/b=(1-x)/y.$

Comment: If $A\ne 0\ne B$ the equation of the line thru $(A,0$) and $(0,B)$ is $x/A+y/B=1.$